# TextBox does not get value in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net

I design a form for author's Personal Information.
All textboxes get value and their value remain after postback (when I click on save button)
but a textbox and a dropdownlist don't get value and after postback their value  is cleared.
HTML Code:

```
<table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
                <td  height="35" colspan="2" bgcolor="#E1DED9" style="border-left-style: 3">
                    <strong>&nbsp;Personal Information</strong></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td  height="25" bgcolor="#F3F3E9" class="style13" style="padding-left: 5px" >
                    Title:</td>
                <td height="20" bgcolor="#F3F3E9" style="padding-top: 3px; padding-bottom: 2px">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtTitle" runat="server" BorderColor="#DFDFC6" 
                        BorderStyle="Solid" Height="18px" Width="50px"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td bgcolor="#F3F3E9" class="style13" height="25" style="padding-left: 5px" >
                    First Name:</td>
                <td bgcolor="#F3F3E9" style="padding-top: 3px; padding-bottom: 2px">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstName" runat="server" BorderColor="#DFDFC6" 
                        BorderStyle="Solid" Height="18px"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td  height="25" bgcolor="#F3F3E9" class="style13" style="padding-left: 5px" >
                    Middle Name:</td>
                <td height="20" bgcolor="#F3F3E9" style="padding-top: 3px; padding-bottom: 2px">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtMidName" runat="server" BorderColor="#DFDFC6" 
                        BorderStyle="Solid" Height="18px"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td  height="25" bgcolor="#F3F3E9" class="style13" style="padding-left: 5px" >
                    Last Name:</td>
                <td height="20" bgcolor="#F3F3E9" style="padding-top: 3px; padding-bottom: 2px">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtLastName" runat="server" BorderColor="#DFDFC6" 
                        BorderStyle="Solid" Height="18px"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td  height="25" bgcolor="#F3F3E9" class="style13" style="padding-left: 5px" >
                    Gender:</td>
                <td height="20" bgcolor="#F3F3E9" style="padding-top: 3px; padding-bottom: 2px">
&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <asp:RadioButton ID="rdbMale" runat="server" Text="Male" GroupName="Gender" />
&nbsp;
                    <asp:RadioButton ID="rdbFemale" runat="server" Text="Female" 
                        GroupName="Gender" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td  height="25" bgcolor="#F3F3E9" class="style13" style="padding-left: 5px" >
                    Phone:</td>
                <td height="20" bgcolor="#F3F3E9" style="padding-top: 3px; padding-bottom: 2px">
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtPhone" runat="server" BorderColor="#DFDFC6" 
                        BorderStyle="Solid" Height="18px"></asp:TextBox>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td  height="25" bgcolor="#F3F3E9" class="style13" style="padding-left: 5px" >
                    Degree:</td>
                <td height="20" bgcolor="#F3F3E9" style="padding-top: 3px; padding-bottom: 2px">
                    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDegree" runat="server">
                        <asp:ListItem>BS</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>MSc</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>PhD</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Prof</asp:ListItem>
                    </asp:DropDownList>
                    <asp:CheckBox ID="ckbIsStudent" runat="server" Text="Student" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td  height="25" bgcolor="#F3F3E9" class="style14" >
                    </td>
                <td bgcolor="#F3F3E9" class="style15" 
                    style="padding-top: 3px; padding-bottom: 2px">
                    </td>
            </tr></table>
```

Behind Code:

```
 protected void btnFinish_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser();
        ProfileCommon userProfile = Profile.GetProfile(user.UserName);
        userProfile.Title = txtTitle.Text;
        userProfile.FirstName = txtFirstName.Text;
        userProfile.MiddleName = txtMidName.Text;
        userProfile.LastName = txtLastName.Text;
        if (rdbMale.Checked==true)
            userProfile.Gender = "Male";
        else if (rdbFemale.Checked==true)
            userProfile.Gender = "Female";
        userProfile.Phone = txtPhone.Text;
        userProfile.Degree = ddlDegree.SelectedValue.ToString();
        if (ckbIsStudent.Checked)
            userProfile.IsStudent = true;
        else
            userProfile.IsStudent = false;
        userProfile.Save();
}
```

Comment: Magic. provide more information.

Comment: Wild guess: You set/clear them in your OnLoad OUTSIDE of your !IsPostback check. Need to see more code to be sure.

Comment: Please post html and code behind.

Comment: Website or Web Application project?

Comment: Do you set the their values somewehere(f.e. page_load)?

Comment: it is a web site. I write a little code in Page_Load() to show profile information in these textboxes

Comment: thank you @n8wrl, I added if(!Page.IsPostBack) before code in page_load and it solved my problem.

Answer (score -1):

I write the below code in Page_Load() and the problem is solved.

```
 if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            txtTitle.Text = Profile.Title;
            txtFirstName.Text = Profile.FirstName;
            txtMidName.Text = Profile.MiddleName;
            txtLastName.Text = Profile.LastName;
            if (Profile.Gender == "Male")
                rdbMale.Checked = true;
            else if (Profile.Gender == "Female")
                rdbFemale.Checked = true;
            txtPhone.Text = Profile.Phone;
            ddlDegree.Text = Profile.Degree;
        }
```

if (!Page.IsPostBack) was my answer!
thank you geeks...